# Usando findOne() y findOneById con peticiones HTTP (Nodejs + mongoose)

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

Estoy haciendo una api rest en el que quiero hacer peticiones HTTP usando Postman, específicamente quiero realizar una búsqueda o actualizar un documento mongodb, pero esto debe ser por un id que no es el doc_id que proporciona mongo.

Básicamente lo que necesito es que alguien le de una "chequeadita" a mi código y me diga que esta mal o que hace falta. Aca se encuentra la misma pregunta en el foro de stackoverflow en ingles [Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43401790/using-findone-and-findoneandupdate-with-http-request-mongoose/43409650#43409650)

models Schema

```
'use strict'

 const mongoose = require('mongoose')
 const Schema   = mongoose.Schema

 const infoClientSchema = Schema ({
     idusr: String,                          /*Esto es requerido*/
     name: String,
     phone: Number,
     address: String,
     riff: String,
     state: String,
     city: String,
     email: {type: String}
})
```

Controller (Este es el metodo GET que conozco usando findById y funciona)

```
'use strict'

 const InfoCli = require('../models/infoclient')

 function getInfoCli(req, res){
    let infocliId = req.params.infocliId

    InfoCli.findById(infocliId, (err, infocli) =>{
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                request: $(err)'})

        if (!infocli) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                           not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infoclient: infocli})     
    })
 }
```

Controller (Este es el método GET el cual pensé que podría funcionar usando findOne)

```
function getInfoByUsr(req, res){
    let idusr = req.params.idusr

    InfoCli.findOne(idusr, (err, infocli) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                request: $(err)'})

        if (!infocli) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                           not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infoclient: infocli})

        console.log(infocli) /*La consola no esta arrojando nada*/
    })
 }
```

Controller (Este es el método PUT el cual pensé que podría funcionar usando findOneAndUpdate)

```
function updateByUsr(req, res){
    let idusr  = req.params.idusr
    let update = req.body

    InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate(idusr, update, (err, infocliUpdate) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({message: 'Error making 
                                                request: $(err)'})

        if (!idusr) return res.status(404).send({message: 'The client does 
                                                           not exist '})

        res.status(200).send({infocliente: infocliUpdate})
    })
 }
```

Routes (No estoy 100% seguro de esto)

```
const express     = require('express')
const InfoCliCtrl = require('../controllers/infoclient')
const api         = express.Router()

api.get('/infoclient/:infocliId', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoCli) /*working*/
api.get('/infoclient/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```

Answer (score 1):

El método `findOne` **recibe un objeto** que será usado para buscar coincidencias, como lo haces con `find`:

```
InfoCli.findOne({ idusr }, (err, cli) => {
  ...
});

InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate({ idusr }, req.body, (err, cli) => {

});
```

**PD:** Trata de usar promesas en lugar de callbacks; este año es estandarizado `async/await` y los frameworks lo implementarán paulatinamente.

Promesas normales:

```
InfoCli
  .findOne({ idusr })
  .then(doc) => {

  })
  .catch(err => {

  });
```

Usando `async/await`:

```
try {
  const cli = await InfoCli.findOne({ idusr });
} catch (e) {
  // error
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, te tomare la sugerencia con respecto a async/await y me pondré en ello .. De momento me gustaría una solución para mi ejemplo las peticiones me responde con (err) ¿Alguna sugerencia mas?.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que tienes ahora?

Answer (score 1):

En tu código, los metodos `findOne()` y `findById()` los estas utilizando de forma correcta.

`findOne()`

Requiere dos parametros (en su forma mas básica), el primero es un objeto que sirve para localizar el documento a través de coincidencias y el segundo que es un callback que contiene el posible error o usuario, según corresponda, que devuelve la consulta.

`findById()`

Es similar, solo que como primer parametro recibe el **id** del documento a consultar.

Para tu controller correspondiente al PUT, debes tener en cuenta que el método `findOneAndUpdate()`, de la forma en la que lo estas utilizando, te devolverá, a través del callback, el documento correspondiente al usuario **SIN HABER SIDO ACTUALIZADO**. ojo: Esto no significa que no se haya hecho la actualización.

Para que tu método devuelva el documento con las actualizaciones incluidas debes agregar un parametro mas a la consulta:

```
{new:true}
```

Quedando de la siguiente manera:

```
InfoCli.findOneAndUpdate(idusr, update, {new:true}, function(e, usr){
    //Aqui va el resto de tu código
});
```

Te recomendaría leer la documentación de [Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html) y que practiques, al igual que incorpores validaciones en tu Esquema

Y en cuanto a la primera respuesta, concuerdo en que deberías implementar el uso de promesas o `async/await`, siempre y cuando entiendas a la perfección como funciona la asincronía y el uso de los callbacks.

Comment: Muchas gracias, modificare el controller para que devuelva el modificado. Por otro lado los metodos aun estando bien empleados me responden con (err)

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar el error que te devuelve. Usa un console.log(err); para que te imprima de que se trata.

Comment: O puedes abrir otra pregunta en la que hagas referencia especifica al error.

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias a todos por su ayuda, el problema fue un horrible error de mi parte en las rutas de la api

de esta manera me encontraba usando dos rutas para la misma petición:

```
api.get('/infoclient/:infocliId', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoCli) /*working*/
api.get('/infoclient/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```

por supuesto al colocar el identificador para el **idusr** entraba en conflicto con la búsqueda del **ObjectId**

de esta manera se corrigior todo:

```
api.get('/infoclient/idusr/:idusr', InfoCliCtrl.getInfoByUsr)
```